# Can't run snakeviz. What might be the problem here?

Tags: python, snakeviz

When I ran `$ snakeviz code_profile.prof` from CLI :

`snakeviz web server started on 127.0.0.1:8080; enter Ctrl-C to exit http://127.0.0.1:8080/snakeviz/%2Fhome%2Fatmadeep%2FProjects%2FtrafficAI-master%2Fprofile_info-60.prof snakeviz: error: no web browser found: could not locate runnable browser`

After some search, I tried running it in server only mode and got this error using  `--server` argument :

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/atmadeep/anaconda3/envs/work-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1681, in _execute result = self.prepare() File "/home/atmadeep/anaconda3/envs/work-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2430, in prepare raise HTTPError(self._status_code) tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found`

What might be the problem here? Is the profile generated corrupt or am I not understanding something related to snakeviz.

Note: **I'm not running this code in jupyter-notebook**.

Comment: Hi @user5662689! Have you solved this problem by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

So, here's the solution. from the console, run:

`$python -m snakeviz profile.prof --server`

When running from console, `snakeviz` needs to be called as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

on a server you have to add --server argument and to click on the link in the terminal. Putting a threshold at 1/100 helps also.